# Using http post method in android

Tags: android

Please suggest me, how to use http post method.

I want to sent the data back to PHP server like this format:

```
    {
  "customer_detail": {
    "customer_phone": "6774980865",
    "customer_comments": "Enter Your comments here...gvhhxjkjs",
    "customer_email": "prasanth@dunamis.com",
    "customer_name": "prasanth"
  },
  "feedBack": [
    {
      "qu_id": "1",
      "feedans": "Good"
    },
    {
      "qu_id": "2",
      "feedans": "Good"
    },
    {
      "qu_id": "3",
      "feedans": "Bad"
    },
    {
      "qu_id": "4",
      "feedans": "Bad"
    },
    {
      "qu_id": "5",
      "feedans": "Excellent"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please provide me solution.

Comment: That's JSON and it's a valid body for a HTTP POST. You should set the `content-type` header to `application/json`. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to make POST Request :

```
public String makePOSTRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    String response = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "POST Response >>> " + response);
    return response;

}
```

Usage :

In Java :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",jsonObject.toString()));

String response = makePOSTRequest(String url, nameValuePairs );
```

Server Side Php :

```
$jsonInput = $_POST['json'];
json_decode($jsonInput);
```